# Does a CPU generate less heat than the electricity consumed, when it is calculating and storing results?

Tags: energy, entropy, work

Bringing order to the bits stored in RAM or on disk is a form of work.

Does this mean that a CPU generates less heat than the electricity consumed, when it is calculating *and storing* results?

Do DRAM chips release a tiny bit of heat when power is removed and their (ordered) content fades?

Is this "ordering work" a millionth, billionth, or trillionth of the electrical energy consumed?